# How to signal a person driving behind you to stop texting?

Tags: car

This has become a real issue for me these days. I have been rear-ended twice already so I started paying attention more to what the person driving behind me is doing. When I see 'texters', I usually try to change lane but there are times when I simply can't.

How should I signal the person behind me to stop texting while driving?

Comment: @jamesqf If you have an answer, please post it below. Comments are ill fit to vet the information people post. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: If I do that, someone is sure to complain that it is not a proper answer.  Which in this case it wasn't, since it was a comment on the impossibility of doing what the OP wants - at least by any legal method.

Comment: @jamesqf If you can say there's no way legally with some degree authority, then that is a perfectly legitimate answer. But if you don't have a "proper answer" (your words), then that doesn't make it better as a comment. The problem is comments cannot be down-voted if they are wrong; or edited to correct that. At best, you can hope to trigger an argument or discussion about the correctness (or lack of) of your *answer,* and that isn't want comments are for either.

Comment: Short answer. You don't contact the crazy driver behind you. You either let them pass, or drive more carefully. I would change lanes to let them pass.

Comment: My experience: You cannot teach people. Everytime you realise a situation of increased danger, increase your safety distance so you 1) have more reaction time 2) can utilize longer braking distances. This has saved my ass at least several times, last time it was a near catastrophe when someone in front of me crashed into the barrier at 130 kph (but recovered), with 4 tailgaters behind him/her and 2 tailgaters behind myself. It's unthankful, as you will also save the ass of the tailgating idiot, but well, read into Zen.

Comment: yell at them out the window?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/440/

Comment: If you happen to have their phone number, text them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't like to spend too much time looking in my rearview mirror instead of looking ahead, so here's what I do:
- If I'm concerned about safety, I pull over at the first, safe opportunity to let the driver around me. I don't have the authority of law enforcement, so I cannot educate anyone. All I can do is create a safe space where/when possible.
- If I can't pull over, I put on my flashing emergency lights. This works in all cases. I've never had it fail.

Hand signals can be misunderstood. Same goes for horns. I tap my horn to alert someone if they can go ahead of me (simple communication), if they are getting too close to me and I can't move (informative alert), and (rarely) lay on my horn to communicate a serious danger. That doesn't mean I don't get angry, but drivers have rudimentary tools to communicate and the law dictates how we can respond, so I have to manage my emotions on the road.

I will say, pulling over or choosing to back off and calm down, provides near-immediate relief from stress. I've never regretted making the safer choice. I drive, for the most part, happy and chilled out because of it.

I've lived in 6 states, one territory, done two cross-country trips, and driven a 36-state loop. I've seen all manner of behavior and weather conditions and terrains, and it's best to just be happy, hang back, watch the traffic patterns, help when you can, don't get too riled, and kindly use those emergency flashers to communicate to those behind you to pay attention or watch out. We have to share the road - people have varying degrees of maturity and problem-solving skills. We don't just carry our cargo (kids, groceries, work stuff), we are also carrying the stresses of the day. So it's basically a crapshoot. You just do the best you can. Be safe. Make it home to the family who loves you. We have to look out for each other.

Answer (score 7):

If it's safe to do so, pull over and let them pass.  Do *not* step on the brake; you'll just collect them on the rear bumper (and suing them afterward usually doesn't make things better).

Comment: Having to pay the increased insurance rates after a rear-end is often the most effective way to teach stubborn people that texting while driving is not a good idea.

Comment: Once again, that requires the lesson be applied after it's needed.  Ideally, they'd get the message before they do a bunch of property damage and potentially injure (or even kill) someone.

Answer (score 6):

You might consider installing a rear-facing "dash-cam" to document the condition of following drivers; that way, next time you get rear-ended (inevitable, if you drive in traffic with texters), you'll have the documentation you need to sue them for enough to make the papers -- which **might** make a difference to everyone affected by this.

If you're concerned about privacy (you shouldn't be, when you're trying to protect yourself against the negligence of others), you could install an **obvious** dummy camera -- perhaps buy an old VHS-C camcorder at a thrift store, or similar.  One that doesn't actually work, but makes it *appear* that you're recording people (tailgating, texting behind you, etc.).

Comment: I'm iffy about recording someone without their consent..

Comment: The highway or city street is a public place with no reasonable expectation of privacy -- especially against recording what's already a violation of the law most places (texting while driving).

Comment: It's still without the other party's consent.

Comment: @JustDoIt Then how are dash cams legally sold then?

Comment: I never said they were illegal, I said I'm iffy about recording someone without their consent @eYe I am aware that dash cams are legal. I just don't like the whole approach

Comment: Answer edited to address concerns in comments.

Comment: @JustDoIt. You're in public. You can record whatever you see in public. If someone wants privacy, avoid doing things in public view. You are not compromising anyone's privacy in public. What you must not do is distribute what you record for your own self-defense and private use. I might be wrong; but, I never in doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Beep you horn, to get their attention. Your horn is there to make people aware of your presence and if someone is at risk of running into the back of you because they aren't paying enough attention, it's a perfectly legitimate use of the horn.

Comment: Would the downvoter be kind enough to explain what they see as the problem with this post?

Comment: It wasn't me, but if I had to guess, it's because your horn-honking could distract other drivers/pedestrians/etc and also possibly not even get the attention of the person behind you.

Comment: It's true that the horn is indiscriminate in whose attention it gets, but if it's not for alerting of an imminent collision, what is it for? I would have thought almost all texters would look up from their phone if they hear a horn.

Comment: I also think that texters would look up, but that requires them perceiving the horn. Never underestimate the stupidity and inattentiveness of anyone. People are literally the worst.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Physiology** *Defensively* to **Make Yourself As Conspicuous As Possible**.

If/when you feel you are being followed too closely, increase your visibility by turning on your four-way flasher/hazard lights to get the conscious attention of the other driver before making any changes to your speed or direction.

Flashing lights are one of the first stimuli in our order of perception. Even our peripheral vision has sensitivity to flashing lights.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears to be a common issue in your route you can keep handy a sign with big font letters glued to a stick and just horn and show it from the window.

Comment: This sounds very much like a recipe to bring on road rage -- and the texting driver already isn't paying attention to other traffic, so won't even benefit from the sign.

Comment: that is why i suggested for him to HORN first

Answer (score 2):

Someone mentioned posting a sign. Reminded me of something I tried. I used to commute GA-400 into Atlanta, in the slow lane, going 10 mph over the speed limit, and I would still get tailed by a speeder. I've even had someone honk his horn and shake his fist because I wasn't going 20mph over the speed limit in the fast lane. 
I always used my commute to learn something about people-dynamics. And I'd brainstorm about the "perfect bumper sticker" that would resolve situations. 
So I came up with a 70-point (homemade, pre Cafe Press days) bumper sticker that said Why Hurray?
I slapped that on with some clear packing tape. It worked beautifully. I couldn't count the number of cars that would come screaming up behind me, zoom in tight, then read the sticker, back way off, sometimes going around me. I don't think it ticked anyone off. I think it just gave them pause to think, and also to know that I was going as fast as I was going and it was futile to push, as I chose not to hurry.
I learned a few other fun things, too:
Driver's are trained to be defensive. And that's fine. But when we take it too far we miss out on little opportunities to help one another. Not a big deal, just something I noticed. For instance, most drivers wait to put on turn signals to change lanes because they believe that the car in that lane will close the gap. They believe this because it happens. So they wait to signal because they don't want to trigger defensive behavior that will cause them to lose the opportunity to move over. 
I tested that theory in moderate commuter traffic. Every time I signaled in advance, the car in the lane I wanted sped up and closed the gap. 
But, and this is what makes it all worthwhile, when I kept the signal on, and didn't hug the dotted line or do anything else aggressive, just cruised a long in my lane, my signal became more like a request. The driver perceived that I was asking with that signal, instead of demanding, and the driver (in all cases) backed off and kindly let me in. So even the people who come off as rude aren't really rude after all. At least that's my takeaway.

Comment: For both the bumper sticker and the signal technique, I'd give two up votes if I could.  Neither one directly addresses the texting tailgater, but they're wonderful ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted this as an answer to a similar question before but it got so many downvotes that I deleted it. Hopefully the OP will find this technique as useful as I have done for the last 30 years. I'm less inclined to delete it again either way.

I have mastered the technique of left-foot braking. Most importantly, I am able to make my brake lights activate with virtually no braking action taking place.

The offending driver behind you will look up from their phone and expect all to be the same as it was when they looked down, however, in the meantime, you have touched the brake pedal with your left foot. They panic and overreact, you drive on, releasing the brake pedal. After this happens a few times they will realise they aren't able to drive behind you whilst texting.

Personally, I've never been concerned about someone rear-ending my car (which has never happened in 30 years I might add), they are implictly in the wrong having done so and it will cost them big money. For this reason, I am happy to use a secondary technique in these situations as well. Having seen my brake lights activated when I am not braking, I then go on to use my handbrake when I AM braking - which slows the car without activating the brakelights at all.

The combination of both techniques is incredibly potent when used on people who are not concentrating, they automatically switch to a different driving style where the road becomes the focus of their attention. I have actually seen this happen by watching them in my rear-view mirror, the eyes spend 90% of the time looking out of the car rather than the 10% they were previously giving.

Comment: The handbrake technique you describe could easily be seen as *intending* to cause a crash -- and transfers fault from the driver behind, who *was* in the wrong before, to the driver who bypasses his brake lights.  In other words, you're taking liability on yourself by doing this -- and if someone is badly injured or killed in the resulting crash, could be culpable (even the point of manslaughter).  BTW, your left foot braking could also cause an accident, when the driver behind panic-brakes.  Both of these are very irresponsible, at a minimum.

Comment: @ZeissIkon this was the same sort of nonsense that caused me to delete my answer before it's no more justified this time. How are they going to prove that my brake lights didn't operate? Even if they have a dash cam and are able to conclusively prove (by some means I can't imagine) that I "intended" manslaughter, they then have to overturn the well-established principle that you are actually supposed to look where you're going and leave enough braking distance. Good luck with that.

Comment: Interesting approach, but terrible driving habits.

Comment: @Lefty Proof or lack thereof doesn't change the fact that you're acting in a manner that will cause, rather than prevent accidents.  Your positive action makes you culpable, even if you're never caught.

Comment: Brake-checking is stupid, illegal and dangerous. Don't do this.

Comment: This is not brake-checking. Read the actual words.